# nested div classes with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need some help with nested classes with javascript.
I made image, title, date and btn classes but I need a container that can cover these divs. I use createElement and setAttribute to make these divs but I have no idea how can I make a container with createElement with javascript. Thank you.

```
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1>Titles</h1>
    <h2>Desc</h2>
    <input id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Enter">
    <button id="search-btn" onclick="requested()">Search</button>
    <div class="my-galaxy">My Galaxy</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
function loaded() {
for (let i = 0; i < MAX_PAGE; i++) {
    const img = document.createElement('div');
    img.setAttribute("class", "image");
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    const title = document.createElement('div');
    title.setAttribute("class", "title");
    document.body.appendChild(title);

    const date = document.createElement('div');
    date.setAttribute("class", "date");
    document.body.appendChild(date);

    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.setAttribute("id", "btn");
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you not have a `<div id='container'></div>` already on the page waiting for things to be appended into?

Comment: I need to add the container div as dynamic way : (

Comment: Does it have to wrap the elements you are adding? Where this `container` div should be placed?

Comment: You can do `const someElement = document.createElement('div');` then simply do `someOtherElement.append(someElement);`

Comment: Yes container wrap the image, title, date and btn divs. So it has to be inside the for loop. The container div should be at the beginning of the body tag.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you just need to create the container first, then append everything inside it. I will assume you want a separate container for each set of data, something like:

```
function loaded() {

  for (let i = 0; i < MAX_PAGE; i++) {
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.classList.add('container');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    const img = document.createElement('div');
    img.setAttribute("class", "image");
    container.appendChild(img);

    const title = document.createElement('div');
    title.setAttribute("class", "title");
    container.appendChild(title);

    const date = document.createElement('div');
    date.setAttribute("class", "date");
    container.appendChild(date);

    const btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.setAttribute("id", "btn");
    container.appendChild(btn);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Kinglish , the page can already come with a `container` that you append to using JavaScript, or you can create that container by appending it to document:

You do this by calling JavaScript `div` functions on an element selected y id (container) rather than 'document' directly.

```js
function loaded() {
//set Constants
  var MAX_PAGE =5;
  var color=['red','yellow','green','blue','orange'];
  //Get refrence to the exsisting container object
  var baseContainer1 = document.getElementById('container1');
  
  //Create a new container object
  var baseContainer = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(baseContainer);
  baseContainer.id="container";
  baseContainer.style.backgroundColor='green';
  baseContainer.innerHTML="Dynamic Container:\n";
  
  //Add elements to container object. For each child Element, create a new container element for that 'loop' in the for loop
  for (let i = 0; i < MAX_PAGE; i++) {
      var container = document.createElement('div');
      container.innerHTML='innerContainer(made dynamically):\n'
      container.id=("innerContainer"+i);
      container.style.fontWeight='bold';
      container.style.backgroundColor=color[i];
      container.style.border='1px black solid';
      container.style.margin='3px';
      const img = document.createElement('div');
      img.setAttribute("class", "image");
      img.innerHTML= 'img\n';
      container.appendChild(img);
      
      const title = document.createElement('div');
      title.setAttribute("class", "title");
      title.innerHTML= 'title\n';
      container.appendChild(title);

      const date = document.createElement('div');
      date.setAttribute("class", "date");
      date.innerHTML= 'date\n';
      container.appendChild(date);

      const btn = document.createElement('button');
      btn.setAttribute("id", "btn");
      btn.innerHTML= 'btn\n';
      container.appendChild(btn);

      baseContainer.appendChild(container.cloneNode(true)); //Use clone node as created element can't be used twice at once);
      baseContainer1.appendChild(container.cloneNode(true)); //Use clone node as created element can't be used twice at once);
  }
}
loaded();
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
      <h1>Titles</h1>
      <h2>Desc</h2>
      <input id="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Enter">
      <button id="search-btn" onclick="requested()">Search</button>
      <div class="my-galaxy">My Galaxy</div>
      <div id="container1" style="font-weight:bold;background-color:red">Container: </div>
  </div>
</body>
```